# Loss of Worklight Server Connection without hearbeat interval

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Worklight 6.1.0.1 If I have a worklight server session timeout set to 1 hour, and I don't have a heartbeat interval set.  The application starts, and establishes a connection with the WL server.

The WL server is shutdown, and not restarted.  If the application does not invoke any back requests to the WL server (ex: connect, adapter, etc) while the server is stopped will the loss of connection be detected, or would I have had to set a heartbeat interval to cause the loss of connection to be detected?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not write applicative code to handle off line scenarios, none is going to do that for you.

Consult with the [Working Offline training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development).

Comment: Yes, I agree, was interested if WL detects a loss of connection even when the app has not set a heartbeat, and not accessed the server. Is there any internal WL client <-> server exchange to detect loss of connection even though the application has not implemented (Heatbeat) or executed (Bacend activity) to cause the detection.

Comment: Heartbeat is enabled by default for 20 minutes, but you say you disabled it. so... implement a mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the loss of server connection please use the following

- Events that are fired only on change of connectivity state. Success <--> Failure
  `WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED` and `WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED`. For more info see this [link](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc%2Fhtml%2Frefjavascript-client%2Fhtml%2FWL.Client.html&path%3D0_9_0_0_1_7_2)
- use `onConnectionFailure` in initOptions to figure out server connection failure.
  See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047477/worklight-method-for-checking-connection) for more info.